# Remove space after an display inline-block list

Tags: html, css

It's strange, my unsorted list with `display: inline-block` is inside an `height: auto` div element. But the div is 3px higher then the unsorted list. Do someone see the problem ?

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: monospace;
}
#main_navigation {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3e3e3e;
    text-align: center;
}
#main_navigation img {
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1em;
    top: 0.5em;
}
#main_navigation ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
#main_navigation ul li {
    padding: 2em;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table-cell;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
#main_navigation ul li:hover {
    background-color: #e04100;
}
#main_navigation ul li:first-child {
    display: none;
}
#main_navigation ul li:nth-child(2) {
    border: none;
}
#main_navigation ul li a {
    font-size: 1.75em;
    color: #cecece;
    padding: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="main_navigation"> <a href="#"><img src="res/logo.png"></a>
    <ul id="main_navigation_ul">
        <li>Navigation
            <div id="menu_symbol" onclick="nav_toggle()">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </li>
        <li><a href="google.de">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About me</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Imprint</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hkp0bq4d/)
You can see the space very good by hovering over the nav points.

Comment: You might add some HTML code. Try to use jsfiddle or something like that! For now, use dev tools from Chrome or FireFox to see what is exactly taking the 3px extra. Might it be a padding, marging, border?

Comment: @Timo002 First thx for editing :) Second ok i think about it next time. I already tried to figure out why there are 3 additional pxs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `vertical-align` value on your list: [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hkp0bq4d/1/)

```
#main_navigation ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but can you explain what vertical-align does in this example ? :)

Answer (score 2):

The extra pixels come from the fact that the element with `display: inline-block` is an inline element, so it will be treated as a character on a text line.

The element is placed on the base line of the text line, and there is space below the base line for hanging characters like `j` and `g`. That's where the extra pixels come from.

From what I can tell, you can just remove the `display: inline-block` style without any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation, first Natsu already solve it :) second i need display inline-block because it centers the unsorted list in the middle on the screen.